# Inequality on a domain and on compact subsets of the domain

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$. Suppose
$$u > 0 \quad \text{a.e. on compact subsets of $\Omega$}.$$
Does this imply that
$$u > 0 \quad \text{a.e. on $\Omega$}?$$
This is trivially true, isn't it? Because we can exhaust almost every  point of $\Omega$ by compact subsets. The two statements are equivalent?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $u > 0$ a.e. on **every** compact subsets of $\Omega$?

Comment: @alphaomega right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. It's immediate from the inner regularity of Lebesgue measure $\lambda^d$.